# Cannot do Ctrl+Alt+F1 after login

Tags: 16.04, tty

I can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to switch to tty1 at the login screen. However, as soon as I log in that key combination does nothing.

I can still do `sudo chvt 1`, which is not useful for when I get a unresponsive full-screen chrome window. Any ideas?